# How to Navigate from screen A to B and fetch API to display on screen B by ID?

Tags: android

I want to make each card clickable and navigate from screen A to B. On Screen A it contains list view of card already. At screen B, I want to display each information in detail about each card from this Api.

Api Link : https://api.test.dev3.coolbeans.studio/books

This is my API Class

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("/books")
suspend fun getBooks(): Response

companion object {
    private var apiInterface: ApiInterface? = null

    fun getInstance(): ApiInterface {
        if (apiInterface == null) {
            apiInterface = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.test.dev3.coolbeans.studio")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
                .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        }

        return apiInterface!!
    }
}}
```

This is my HomeScreen

```
    @Composable
fun HomeScreen (book: BookDetail) {
    Card(
        backgroundColor = Color.White, elevation = 2.dp, modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 10.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(all = 10.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Column {
                Text(
                    text = "Id: ${book.id}",
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = 14.sp),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 4.dp)
                )
                Text(
                    text = "Title: ${book.title}",
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = 14.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 4.dp)
                )
                Text(
                    text = "Description: ${book.description}",
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = 14.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Justify),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 4.dp)
                )
                Text(
                    text = "Author: ${book.author}",
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = 14.sp),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 4.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val bookViewModel by viewModels<BookViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BookList(bookList = bookViewModel.bookListResponse)
            bookViewModel.getBookList()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BookList(bookList: List<BookDetail>) {
    LazyColumn {
        itemsIndexed(items = bookList) { index, item ->
            HomeScreen(book = item)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my BookViewModel

```
class BookViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var bookListResponse: List<BookDetail> by mutableStateOf(listOf())
    var errorMessage: String by mutableStateOf("")

    fun getBookList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val apiInterface = ApiInterface.getInstance()

            try {
                apiInterface.getBooks().let{
                    bookListResponse = it.rows
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                errorMessage = e.message.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my BookDetail (Model class)

```
data class BookDetail(
    val author: String,
    val description: String,
    val id: String,
    val thumbnailUrl: String,
    val title: String
)

data class Response(
    val count: Int,
    val rows: List<BookDetail>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow along this tutorial to show this data on recycler view. https://www.section.io/engineering-education/handling-recyclerview-clicks-the-right-way/

Once You have setup the recycler view and adapter then you can go ahead with the below implementation.

Now First, make sure the `BookDetail` class implements the `Serializable` interface:

```
class BookDetail : Serializable {
// your stuff
}
```

then on each item's click you can start the activity B and send `BookDetails` to it using intents. eg:

```
fun launchNextScreen(context: Context, book: BookDetail): Intent {
   val intent = Intent(context, NextScreenActivity::class.java)
   intent.putExtra("book_details", book)
   return intent
}

startActivity(launchNextScreen())
```

To receive `BookDetail` back from on Activity B Intent you'll need to call:

```
val bookDetail = intent.getSerializableExtra("book_details") as? BookDetail
```